# how to differ 0 from FALSE when using in_array

Tags: php

i have a function to filter unwanted values in array (usually false and empty values)  here it is :

```
function filter_array($arr ,  $filter = array('' , FALSE)){

    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(in_array(trim($v) , $filter)) 
        unset($arr[$k]);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

here is the problem , it considering `0` as `false` and removing them from array ... how can i fix this ?

one way is to loop trough `$filter`  and  and use `===` to check the values but i want to avoid another loop

Comment: [Read the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Strict comparison is in the third argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) takes a third optional argument for strict comparison.

```
in_array(trim($v) , $filter, true)
```